# Logstash grok pattern for [2017-08-19T12:47:43,822][INFO][logstash.agent] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Tags: logstash-grok

Can anyone give the logstash grok pattern for below lines.  I want to take only timestamp alone.

```
[2017-08-19T12:47:43,822][INFO][logstash.agent] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-08-19T12:49:47,213][WARN][logstash.agent] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Comment: Indent code for SO formatting

Comment: Any update on this? Did my answer help to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but here are two possible solutions:

- [%{GREEDYDATA:date1}][%{LOGLEVEL:debugLevel}][%{USERNAME:agentName}] %{GREEDYDATA:message} [%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date2}][%{LOGLEVEL:debugLevel2}][%{USERNAME:agentName2}] %{GREEDYDATA:message}

This grok pattern will extract all information that you have in your log, then you decide if you want to use date1 or date2 field

- %{GREEDYDATA:trash}[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}]%{GREEDYDATA:trash}

This one will only return the second date of your log

Hope it helped !

Comment: {
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59981cc1054e142810000001" }, "@timestamp" : { "$date" : "2017-08-19T16:40:57.154+0530" }, "@version" : "1", "host" : "01hw791865", "message" : "[2017-08-19T12:47:43,822][INFO][logstash.agent] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}", "tags" : [ "_grokparsefailure" ] } ", "tags" : [ "_grokparsefailure" ] }
  ],

  "total_rows" : 2 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}

Comment: It returns grokparsefailure tag

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the timestamp, this should do:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}\]
```

Results for your two loglines on https://grokconstructor.appspot.com:
[image: Result]

---

If you want to match the whole pattern something like this may fit your needs:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]\[%{GREEDYDATA:agent}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Results:
[image: Results]